# denormalize matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization, denormalized

I have a N x K matrix in R, where each row is a observation and each column is a variable that has a fixed lower and upper bound.

My matrix is initially set with values between 0 and 1. What's the best way to de-normalize this matrix? I'm using the following function:

```
denormalizeMult = function(m, lb, ub)
{
 nobs = nrow(m)
 nvars = ncol(m)
 lbDiag = diag(lb, ncol = nvars)
 rangeM = diag(ub - lb, ncol = nvars) 

 m%*%rangeM + matrix(rep(lb, nobs), nrow = nobs, byrow = TRUE)
}

 # Example:
 # 3 variables, 9 observations
 x = matrix(runif(3*9), ncol = 3)

 # to denormalize a variable xi, just do lb[i] + (ub[i] - lb[i])*xi
 # ranges for each variable
 lb = c(-1,-2,-3)
 ub = c(1,2,3)
```

The first variable ranges from -1 to 1, the second from -2 to 2, and so on...
Another solution is:

```
   denormalize2 = function(population)
   {
     r = nrow(population)
     c = ncol(population)
     decm = matrix(rep(0, r*c), r, c)

     for(i in 1:r)
           decm[i,] = lb + (ub - lb) * population[i,]       
     decm
 }
```

Is there a simple (and faster) way  to achieve this?
Thanks!

EDIT: Results from the answers below:

[image: Results from the answers below:]

Comment: Please provide a minimal example data set, with `m`, `lb`, and `ub`. Absent that, I'd simply suggest you have a look at `?sweep`.

Comment: I feel there is something wrong in the way you are filling `lbM` and `rangeM`. Should you be using `rep(..., each = nobs)` or `matrix(..., byrow = TRUE)`?

Comment: Anyway, this function is not doing the work...i've edited it again, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a double transpose:

```
t(lb + t(x) * (ub - lb))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `sweep()`:

```
## Example data
x <- matrix(c(0,0.5,1), nrow=3, ncol=3)  # A better example for testing 
lb = c(-1,-2,-3)
ub = c(1,2,3)

sweep(sweep(x, 2, ub-lb, FUN="*"), 2, lb, FUN="+")
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   -1   -2   -3
# [2,]    0    0    0
# [3,]    1    2    3
```

Comment: Thanks, the results matches with my first solution above...now i don't know which one is more efficient - i'll try some tests!

Comment: I wouldn't sweat it. In my opinion, flodel's solution is cleverer and more elegant, while mine *may* be easier to look at later and quickly see what it does and how.

Comment: I ran some tests with a 2000x10 Matrix, 1000 runs for each function. The results (user, system, elapsed): **sweepFunction** = (1.544, 0.860, 2.382). **matrixMultFunction** = (1.227, 0.772, 1.981). **transposeFunction** = (0.658, 0.955, 1.598) - Thanks again

Comment: @Fernando -- Here's the corrected version of my earlier comment, (using `n <- nrow(x)` rather than `n <- ncol(x)`).  If speed is what you're after, this should be fairly competitive: `n <- nrow(x); x * rep(ub-lb, each=n) + rep(lb, each=n)`. It should be faster than @flodel's because it avoids the time-consuming matrix transpositions. (Thanks, by the way, for catching my earlier error.)

Comment: Thank you - i'm running a evolutionary algorithm with a lot of rows, this code will help a lot. I'll post a new test with the correct version!

Comment: One more thing: with tests like the nifty ones you added to your post, it's also worth checking that the results of all the algorithms are identical, using `identical(a,b)`, `identical(b,c)`, etc. Cheers.